# How to merge two pages based on the format Locator result in KTM?

Tags: kofax

How to merge two pages based on the format Locator result? Suppose if there are 10 pages document and if the Invoice number in Page 1 and 2 or same it must be considered as one document and remaining 8 must be treated as 8 documents.

I have tried to get the Alternatives and getting the error while merging